# What is the name of this Python comparison?

Tags: python, comparison

I found this function

```
def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
    return age
```

This is the first time that I saw this type of comparison. So, I did a few test,

```
>>> (5,4)<(7,5)
True
>>> (5,4)<(7,3)
True
>>> (5,4)<(4,3)
False
>>> (5,4)<(4,8)
False
>>> (5,4)<(5,8)
True
>>> (5,4)<(5,3)
False
>>> (5,4)<(5,4)
False
>>> (5,4)<=(5,4)
True
>>> (5,4,1)<(5,4,9)
True
>>> (5,4,1,7)<(5,4,1,6)
False
>>> (5,4,1,7)<(5,4,1,8)
True
>>> (5,4,1,7)<(5,4,2,8)
True
>>> (5,4,1,7)<(5,4,2,1)
True
```

This is really useful and I want to know if this type of comparison has a name and where can I find information about it.

Is this only in Python?

Thanks

Comment: It's called "comparison". It just happens to be comparing tuples.

Comment: Consider  `1,1 < 2,2 < 3,3` vs `(1,2) < (2,2) < (3,3)` O my!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just ordinary comparison of tuple objects.  From the [Python language spec](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same length.
>
> If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first differing elements. For example, `cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y])` returns the same as `cmp(x,y)`. If the corresponding element does not exist, the shorter sequence is ordered first (for example, `[1,2] < [1,2,3]`).

Comment: When do you use this Tuples Comparison? Currently I only use it to compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), meaning that you start by comparing the first elements of each tuple, and moving on to the next element only if the current elements are equal.